# How to build Augment Reality application using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I had some basic knowledge on Android Development. Recently heard about Flutter and very interested to work on it. I want to know is it possible to build an augment reality app using flutter and which methods to follow to accomplish this? Please help.

Answer (score 6):

As of now, flutter has no support to 3D. Flutter now is focused to only 2D and the team has long-term plan to offer an optimized 3D api for flutter. You read the faq [here](https://flutter.io/faq/#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter).

Answer (score 2):

I think flutter itself has no AR support until now.

But Flutter still can run native code. So you can build your basic application with Flutter. The AR-parts of your App would need to run in native kotlin/swift code.